# LOAD DATA INPATH table files start with some string in Impala

Tags: sql, hive, impala

Just a simple question, I'm new in Impala.

I want to load data from the HDFS to my datalake using impala.

So I have a csv `this_is_my_data.csv` and what I want to do is load the file without specify all the extension, I mean something like the following:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'user/myuser/this_is.* INTO TABLE my_table
```

This is, a string starting with `this_is` and whatever follows.

If you need some additional information, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/impala_load_data.html) says:

> You can specify the HDFS path of a single file to be moved, or the
>   HDFS path of a directory to move all the files inside that directory.
>   You cannot specify any sort of wildcard to take only some of the files
>   from a directory.

The workaround is to put your files into table directory using `mv` or `cp` command. Check your table directory using DESCRIBE FORMATTED command and run `mv` or `cp` command (in a shell, not Impala of course):

```
hdfs dfs -mv "user/myuser/this_is.*" "/user/cloudera/mytabledir"
```

Or put files you need to load into some directory first then load all the directory.